# SWT.MouseMove Events Not Fired While Dragging

Tags: java, swt

The JavaDoc of the `MouseMoveListener` states: "[...] collection of listeners who will be notified when the mouse moves". Sadly, that's a lie. `SWT.MouseMove` events are not fired when the user drags something. So how do I listen to MouseMove events while dragging?

To replicate the problem, add the following listener to the [simple example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DragandDropexamplesnippetdragtextbetweentwolabels.htm):

```
    Listener listener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            shell.setText(event.x + " - " + event.y);
        }
    };
    label1.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, listener);
    label2.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, listener);
```

The shell title will update the coordinates until the left mouse button is pressed. But I need them always. I tried adding the same listeners to the `DragSource` and `DropTarget` (even though in my real-world-application I won't be able to access them), but to no avail.

Comment: Tried the drag listener? http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FDragDetectListener.html

Comment: @verbose-mode Sure. But it gets fired only once when the drag starts.